# Zoom on Canvas in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I implemented Canvas and ToolBar (in WPF C#) and vector graphics editor like Paint almost. I have a problem with the implementation of the Zoom. As I understand the Zoom:

0) I choose the tool ZoomTool;
1) I choose a point on Canvas;
2) I click on it and all the necessary work happens here :

**1. Moving (shifting) the selected point to the center of Canvas;**

**2. Zoom in 2 times (as an example) relative to the center**

The problem is the implementation of this work (shift and zoom in), how to do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFWyL.png)

Comment: Could you show the code you have, and tell us what is the problem with the code?

Comment: Hi when you provide more info on your question you just edit the original question, not add the info as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
class RecZoomTool : Tool
{
        public RecZoomTool()
        {
        }

        public override void MouseDown(Point mousePosition)
        {
            Point pointDirection = new Point(Creator.CanvasWidth / 2, Creator.CanvasHeight /2);
            Creator.ShearingZoom(Point.Subtract(pointDirection, mousePosition));
            Creator.Zooming(2);
        }
}
```

then --->

```
    public static void Zooming(double delta)
    {
        foreach (var figure in Figures)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < figure.coordinates.Count; j++)
            {
                figure.coordinates[j] = new Point(
                    figure.coordinates[j].X * scaleZoom,
                    figure.coordinates[j].Y * scaleZoom
                );
            }
        }

    //    scaleZoom += delta;
    }
    public static void ShearingZoom(Point dPoint, Point mPoint)
    {
        foreach (var figure in Figures)
        {
            Vector delta = Point.Subtract(mPoint, dPoint);
            for (int j = 0; j < figure.coordinates.Count; j++)
            {
                figure.coordinates[j] = new Point(dPoint.X, dPoint.Y);
                //counterZoom++;
                //delta = Point.Subtract(figure.coordinates[j], dPoint);
                figure.coordinates[j] = Point.Add(figure.coordinates[j], delta);
            }

            offsetPosition += delta;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer for every MouseClick:

```
        public override void MouseDown(Point mousePosition)
        {
            double valueZoom = 2.0;
            Point pointDirection = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
            Creator.Shifting(Point.Subtract(pointDirection, mousePosition));
            Creator.Zooming(valueZoom);
        }
```

And there's in main class:

```
    public static int scaleZoom = 2;
    public static Vector offsetPosition = new Vector(0.0, 0.0);
    public static int counterZoom = 0;

    public static void Zooming(double scaleZoom)
    {
        foreach (var figure in Figures)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < figure.coordinates.Count; j++)
            {
                figure.coordinates[j] = new Point(
                    figure.coordinates[j].X * scaleZoom,
                    figure.coordinates[j].Y * scaleZoom
                );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Shifting(Vector delta)
    {
        offsetPosition = delta / scaleZoom;
        foreach (var figure in Figures)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < figure.coordinates.Count; j++)
            {
                figure.coordinates[j] = Point.Add(figure.coordinates[j], offsetPosition);
            }
        }

    }
```